# How to remove value that does not exist in another list?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have two list `master` and `update`, now the `master` list contains all records available in a table, and the `update` list contains only some record of `master` that need to be updated.

I want exclude from the `master` list all the record that's not contained from the `update` list, so I tried:

```
master.RemoveAll(c => update.Any(x => x.Id != c.Id));
```

this will return 0.

The record are:

```
list_name | id
  master    1
  master    2
  master    3
  master    4
  master    5
  update    3
  update    4
  update    5
```

at the end the `master` list should contains only the records: 3, 4, 5.

What I did wrong?

Comment: master.RemoveAll(i => !update.Exists(k => k.id == i.id));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's fix your code - you remove when *any* item in the `update` matches `master`, so `!=` should be `==`:

```
master.RemoveAll(c => !update.Any(x => x.Id == c.Id));
```

That's all you need for a list of, say, 1000 items or so. If the list is, say, 10,000 items, this could become slow due to O(n<sup>2</sup>) nature of the above algorithm. You can put IDs of `update` into a `HashSet`, and use `Contains` for a potential speed-up:

```
var updateIds = new HashSet<int>(update.Select(u => u.Id));
master.RemoveAll(m => !updateId.Contains(m.Id));
```

Comment: I like the performance hint but my list can max get 400 records, so this is not a problem for me

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for:

```
master.RemoveAll(c => !update.Any(x => x.Id == c.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the method `Intersect` (with a twist). You need an equality comparer.

> *Intersect*: Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

## First solution: Override Equals

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xu7sUV)

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as Item;
        return item == null ? false : this.Id.Equals(item.Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();
}

public static void Main()
{
    var master = (new []{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}).Select(x => new Item {Id = x});
    var update = (new []{ 1, 3, 5}).Select(x => new Item {Id = x});

    // yes all you need is here
    master = master.Intersect(update);

    foreach (var item in master)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
}
```

output

```
1
3
5
```

## Second solution: Create a custom comparer

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LnXbtr)

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    // example
    var master = (new []{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}).Select(x => new Item {Id = x});
    var update = (new []{ 1, 3, 5}).Select(x => new Item {Id = x});

    // everything happens here.
    var master = master.Intersect(update, new KeyEqualityComparer<Item>(s => s.Id));

    foreach (var item in master)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
}

// Interset doest not know how to compare by property. This will help it.
public class KeyEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, object> keyExtractor;

    public KeyEqualityComparer(Func<T, object> keyExtractor) => keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)  => keyExtractor(x).Equals(this.keyExtractor(y));
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) => keyExtractor(obj).GetHashCode();
}
```

output

```
1
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) to simulate an intersect:

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lMKI25)

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var master = (new []{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}).Select(x => new Item {Id = x});
    var update = (new []{ 1, 3, 5}).Select(x => new Item {Id = x});

    // we need to get all update's ids.
    master = master.Join(update.Select(x => x.Id), o => o.Id, id => id, (o, id) => o);

    foreach (var item in master)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    }
}
```

output

```
1
3
5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
var listMaster = new List<Master>();
var listUpdate = new List<Update>();

listMaster.Add(new Master { ID = 1, Name = "Jai" });
listMaster.Add(new Master { ID = 2, Name = "Ram" });
listMaster.Add(new Master { ID = 3, Name = "Amit" });
listMaster.Add(new Master { ID = 4, Name = "Mohan" });
listMaster.Add(new Master { ID = 5, Name = "JAg" });

listUpdate.Add(new Update { ID = 1, Name = "JaiU" });
listUpdate.Add(new Update { ID = 2, Name = "RamU" });
listUpdate.Add(new Update { ID = 3, Name = "ShyamU" });

listMaster.RemoveAll(c => !listUpdate.Any(x => x.ID == c.ID));
```